# Sub report text fields right alignment not working on jasper master report at run time

Tags: jasper-reports

I set right alignment in sub report text fields. Its showing in preview report but when I run this report from java then sub report text fields right alignment are not working.

Here is my java code

```
 try{
  Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
  conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://XYZ-BD-BBI01;user=abc;password=1234;database=myDataTables"); 
  String report="C:\\Users/mainReport.jrxml";
  JasperDesign jd  = JRXmlLoader.load(report);
  String sql = "select * from Report where ReportID = " +  reportID;
  JRDesignQuery query = new JRDesignQuery();
  query.setText(sql);
  jd.setQuery(query);
  JasperReport jr = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jd);   
  Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
  parameters.put("ReportID",1211);
  JasperPrint jp1 = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, parameters, conn);  
  JasperViewer.viewReport(jp1, false);
}catch (Exception ex) {
  ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

[This is the current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09aSk.jpg)

[And I want this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQ5Jf.jpg)

Comment: You should post the small templates with *Java* code  to reproduce the problem

Comment: @Alex I updated my question with java code

Comment: Where are the templates? How did you pass the subreport?

Comment: <subreport>
<reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="14" width="216" height="13" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="d291df22-4520-44f8-9959-bd752aa928d5"/>
    
<subreportParameter name="reportID">
<subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{reportID}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
</subreportParameter>
<connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
<subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "itemsSubreport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
</subreport>

Comment: I passing the subreport this way

Comment: And this is the price text field in itemSubreport        :-                                  <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Top" markup="none">
     <font fontName="DialogInput" size="9" isBold="true"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA['$' + new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00").format($F{FullPrice})]]></textFieldExpression>
   </textField>